# Grouping a List of DateTimes separating each grouping by a interval

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have a list of DateTime. I am also allowing the user to select a Interval which is a int and represents hours.  Also let's say the DateTime list is ordered from the earliest date to the latest date.

If the user selects 6 hours then I would go to the 1st index and see if the 2nd index is within 6 hours of the 1st. If so those 2 are grouped. I then go to the 3rd index and see if it is within 6 hours of the 2nd index if it is then that also goes into the first group. And so on and so on until we come to one that is more than 6 hours later than the previous index. In that case then we would start a second group of DateTime and we would then check the next index to see if it is within 6 hours if so then that would be added to the second group. And so on and so on until the last index.

I was hoping to do this in a nice elegant linq statement. Also speed might be a issue since could potentially be thousands if not tens of thousands of DateTime in list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for a method to group consecutive items while a condition is met.  This is a fairly straightforward method to write in a LINQ-esque style of programming:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupWhile<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        List<T> list = new List<T>() { iterator.Current };

        T previous = iterator.Current;

        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (!predicate(previous, iterator.Current))
            {
                yield return list;
                list = new List<T>();
            }

            list.Add(iterator.Current);
            previous = iterator.Current;
        }
        yield return list;
    }
}
```

Once you have this method you can write:

```
var groups = dates.GroupWhile((previous, current) => previous.AddHours(6) >= current);
```

Comment: That works great.  The var group statement needed to be slightly altered from  <= current   to   >= current